# Hide popup box when clicked anywhere on the document

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make a component with a list of items and when I click on each of the items, it shows me an edit popup. When I click on it again, it hides the edit popup. But I would like to also be able to click anywhere on the document and hide all edit popups (by setting edit_item_visible = false).

I tried v-on-clickaway but since I have a list of items then it would trigger multiple times. And the @click event would trigger first and then the clickaway event would trigger multiple times and hide it right after showing it. I also tried to change the component's data from outside but with no luck.

```
Vue.component('item-list', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="showEdit(index)">
                <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                <div>{{ item.description }}</div>

                <div v-if="edit_item_visible" class="edit-item">
                    Edit this item here...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    data()
    {
        return {
            items: [],
            edit_item_visible: false,
            selected: null,
        };
    },

    methods:
    {
        showEdit(index)
        {
            this.selected = index;
            this.edit_item_visible = !this.edit_item_visible;
        }
    },
});

const App = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
})
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-click-outside what about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to edit multiple items at the same time, you should store the list of edited items, not global `edit_item_visible` flag.

```
    showEdit(item)
    {
        this.selected = item;
        this.editing_items.push(item);
    }


    // v-on-clickaway="cancelEdit(item)"
    cancelEdit(item)
    {
        let idx = this.editing_items.indexOf(item);
        this.editing_items.splice(idx, 1);
    }
```

Comment: my cancelEdit function fires after the showEdit function so it shows it and then hides it immediately.

Comment: hmmm... could you check event target in cancelEdit?

Comment: v-on-clickaway="cancelEdit($event)" - gives me error $event is not defined